# Can a partition of a set be constructed from relations that are NOT equivalence relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Is it true that only kind of relations that can completely and uniquely define a partition in a set is the equivalence relation ?

I'm having a hard problem believing that.

Given an original set $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and certain partition $\{P_1,P_2\}$ where $P_1 = \{a,b,d\}$ and $P_2 = \{c\}$ I could introduce a relation (not equivalence relation) $A \rightarrow A = \{ (a,d),(a,b),(b,d),(c,c) \}$ and from that relation I could still uniquely partition the original set $A$ into $\{P_1,P_2\}$. How? Well the informal process of building subsets out of the ordered pairs, one-by-one.

First $(a,d)$ implies a subset that contains $a,d$.
then $(a,b)$ implies a subset that contains $a,b,d$ (by transitive property).
then $(b,d)$ adds no information
then $(c,c)$ implies a subset containing $c$.
The unique result is the partition $\{a,b,d\}, \{c\}$.

Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something crucial?

Comment: @MJD: Could you please explicate how and why $$(a,b) \& (b, d) \Longrightarrow \text{a subset that contains $a, b, d$ by transitivity ?}$$ We don't know that $A \longrightarrow A$ subsumes transitivity? Also, $(a, d) \notin A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on what exactly you mean by a relation "completely and uniquely defining a partition". In one sense, a partition and an equivalence relation are basically the same thing. That doesn't mean that you can't use other types of relations to define partitions; but it does mean that in doing so you necessarily also define an equivalence relation.

In your example, it seems that you intend to define a partition using the [reflexive transitive symmetric closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_transitive_symmetric_closure#P_closures_of_binary_relations) of a relation $R$. This is the intersection of all equivalence relations containing $R$, or equivalently the unique minimal equivalence relation containing $R$. By defining an equivalence relation, you are at the same time defining a partition.

Comment: I'm trying real hard to understand what is the equivalence relation that i'm implicitly defining when i use my informal process to build a unique partition from my non-equivalence relation but i have no sucess so far.How is it defined and what would be its domain and codomain ?

Comment: @nerdy: Did you follow the link I provided? Do you understand the concept of a closure? Do you understand the two definitions I provided in the second paragraph of the answer? (They're the same as the ones MJD gave in response to your comment.)

Comment: I just followed your link and it became a lot clear.Btw, is it true that the "function" that builds a closure out of a relation is not necessarily injective ? For example, i could choose my old R to be  (d,b),(d,a),(d,b),(c,c)  and that would yield me the same equivalence closure, right ?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a partition of $A$.  Then the natural equivalence relation that corresponds to it is that $p$ is related to $q$ whenever $q$ is in the same part as $p$.

What you are doing is taking a non-equivalence relation and then constructing the "equivalence closure", which is the smallest equivalence relation that contains it.

Your partition, for example, has $d$ in the same part as $b$, even though the original relation omits the pair $(d, b)$. The relation says that the relationship between $d$ and $b$ is asymmetric: It has $(b,d)$ but not $(d,b)$, so $d$ is related to $b$ but $b$ is not related to $d$.  But your partition doesn't capture this asymmetry.

Similarly, your partition has $a$ in the same part as itself, but your original relation says that $a$ should *not* be related to itself, because your original  relation does not include $(a,a)$.  So your partition fails to capture this aspect of the relation.

So the partition that you've constructed is derived from the original relation, but not in the special way that we mean when we say that every partition corresponds to an equivalence relation in a special way.

Comment: How is the equivalence closure that i'm implictly using, defined ? What is its domain and codomain ?

Comment: The equivalence closure of a relation $R$ is defined as the smallest equivalence relation that contains $R$, or alternatively as the intersection of every equivalence relation that contains $R$.  (It comes to the same thing.)  Its domain and codomain are the same as those of $R$.  In your example, you've started with $R=\{ (a,d),(a,b),(b,d),(c,c) \}$ and constructed the equivalence closure $\{ (a,a),(a,d),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b),(b,d),(c,c),(d,a),(d,b), (d,d) \}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you and joriki quickly helped me clarify this doubt.I hadn't heard of the the possibility of buildind new sets that safisfy certain property from old sets.I wish i could choose 2 best answers :(

Comment: I'm glad I could help.